# How to add own class name in angular js validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I need one help.I want to add my defined class name in Angular.js validation.I am explaining my code below.

```
 <div ng-class="{ 'has-error': billdata.email.$touched && billdata.email.$invalid }">
<input type="email" name="email" id="procolgmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Add email id" ng-model="colgemail" ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/">
    </div>
```

Here `has-error` is the default class and it gives the light red color border.I need do it to dark red color. can i add my class instead of its default class ?Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy. You need define your css class in your css file: for example:

```
 .myError {
   border: 1px solid green;
}
```

And now : `<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.email.$touched && billdata.email.$invalid }">`